# How to replicate a correlated sub query with big query

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery doesn't support correlated anti-semi joins. I'm currently struggling through a problem that would be made much easier if the above statement was false.

I have two tables.

- One table contains a repeated integer field of all possible identifiers (ProfileGroupModel.sources)
- The second contains a repeated integer field of of values that have been removed from the "possible" list for an account (PRO.ignoredSourceList)

If Big Query did support this type of query these the are results I'm trying to get:

```
SELECT
  pro.pid,
  prg.sources,
FROM [datastore.PRO] AS pro 
JOIN EACH FLATTEN([datastore.ProfileGroupModel], sources) AS prg ON prg.gid = pro.gid
WHERE prg.sources NOT IN (
  SELECT ignoredSourceList
  FROM FLATTEN([datastore.PRO], ignoredSourceList) as proInner
  WHERE proInner.pid = pro.pid
)
```

Does anyone have any pointers on how to unwind this into a working solution within the BigQuery realm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shooting a little in a dark in terms of exact logic behind above example, but something like below should  work

```
SELECT 
  pro.pid AS pid,
  prg.sources AS source 
FROM [datastore.PRO] AS pro 
JOIN EACH FLATTEN([datastore.ProfileGroupModel], sources) AS prg 
  ON prg.gid = pro.gid
LEFT JOIN EACH FLATTEN([datastore.PRO], ignoredSourceList) AS proInner 
  ON proInner.pid = pro.pid AND  prg.sources = proInner.ignoredSourceList
WHERE proInner.ignoredSourceList IS NULL 
  AND proInner.pid IS NULL
```

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I want. Thanks Mikhail. Interesting chrome extension you guys built. Giving it a try now.